# [WCF]two service in the same process

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes

i have one exe.
in this exe.
i start a service, call it serviceManager
and then, start another service, call it serviceChild.

when i use serviceChild create a channel with serviceManager,
call the serviceManager's callback.
it will freez.

all the service binding is netnamedpipebinding.

who can tell me what is happend?

and my code:
interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
internal interface IChild
{
    [OperationContract]
    CommunicationState GetState();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    CommunicationState GetState();
}
```

and:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Child : IChild
{
    private readonly Guid _address = Guid.NewGuid();
    private readonly ServiceHost _host;

    public Guid Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
    }

    public Child()
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(this);

        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        var clientAddress = Helper.GetClientAddress(_address);
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint((typeof(IChild)), binding, clientAddress);

        _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

        _host.Open();
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        if(!Manager.IsRunning()){Manager.Start();}

        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Constants.ADDRESS_PIPE_SERVER);
        using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IManager>(binding, endpoint))
        {
            IManager managerChannel = null;
            try
            {
                managerChannel = factory.CreateChannel();
                **managerChannel.GetState();**// BUG:<-----
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ex " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Helper.CloseChannel((ICommunicationObject)managerChannel);
            }
        }
    }

    public CommunicationState GetState()
    {
        return _host.State;
    }
}
```

the manager:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Manager : IManager
{
    private static ServiceHost _host;

    private static Manager _instance;

    private static Manager Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Manager()); }
    }

    #region IManager Members

    public CommunicationState GetState()
    {
        return _host.State;
    }

    #endregion

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (_host != null
            && (_host.State == CommunicationState.Created
                || _host.State == CommunicationState.Opening
                || _host.State == CommunicationState.Opened))
        {
            return;
        }


        _host = new ServiceHost(Instance);

        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        var endpoint = Constants.ADDRESS_PIPE_SERVER;
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint((typeof (IManager)), binding, endpoint);
        _host.Open();
    }

    public static bool IsRunning()
    {
        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(Constants.ADDRESS_PIPE_SERVER);
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IManager>(binding, endpointAddress);
        IManager managerChannel = null;
        try
        {
            managerChannel = factory.CreateChannel();
            // wait for server to respond
            if (_host != null && _host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                var contextChannel = managerChannel as IClientChannel;
                if (contextChannel != null) contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            }
            try
            {
                managerChannel.GetState();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Helper.CloseChannel((ICommunicationObject) managerChannel);
        }
    }
```

others:

```
internal static class Helper
{
    public static void CloseChannel(ICommunicationObject channel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Opened) channel.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            channel.Abort();
        }
    }

    public static string GetClientAddress(object serviceAddress)
    {
        return string.Format(Constants.ADDRESS_PIPE_CLIENT_FORMAT, serviceAddress);
    }
}


internal static class Constants
{
    internal static string ADDRESS_PIPE_SERVER = @"net.pipe://localhost/Server";
    internal static string ADDRESS_PIPE_CLIENT_FORMAT = @"net.pipe://localhost/Client_{0}";
}
```

at last , the test:

```
private void ActionLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Manager.Start();
    }

    private void ActionConnectedSelf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new Child();
        client.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Can you **show us some code** ?? E.g. your service contracts, the service implementation, relevant cofing etc.

Comment: I think you're completely misunderstanding the WCF services.... you should **NOT** create and open a `ServiceHost` inside your service implementation class (e.g. `Child`) - those should be **separate items**. The service host will handle incoming requests and it will instantiate service classes to handle those requests...

Comment: ...so... could you show some code. sorry about the novice question.

Comment: See my response - that's how I typically structure my WCF solutions. You need to have (1) a service (and data) contracts - you have that already; (2) you need to **implement** that service - that's just the service methods - nothing about the host or anything!, and (3) you need to **host** your service somewhere - that can be IIS, or a Windows NT Service (or Console app) - that's where you need the `ServiceHost` (unless you use IIS) - so basically you need at least three projects for your server-side part of a serious WCF service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to structure my WCF solutions like this:

**Contracts** (class library)
Contains all the service, operations, fault, and data contracts. Can be shared between server and client in a pure .NET-to-.NET scenario

**Service implementation** (class library)
Contains the code to implement the services, and any support/helper methods needed to achieve this. Nothing else.

**Service host(s)** (optional - can be Winforms, Console App, NT Service)
Contains service host(s) for debugging/testing, or possibly also for production.

This basically gives me the server-side of things.

On the client side:

**Client proxies** (class library)
I like to package my client proxies into a separate class library, so that they can be reused by multiple actual client apps. This can be done using svcutil or "Add Service Reference" and manually tweaking the resulting horrible app.config's, or by doing manual implementation of client proxies (when sharing the contracts assembly) using `ClientBase<T>` or `ChannelFactory<T>` constructs.

**1-n actual clients** (any type of app)
Will typically only reference the client proxies assembly, or maybe the contracts assembly, too, if it's being shared. This can be ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms, console app, other services - you name it.

That way; I have a nice and clean layout, I use it consistently over and over again, and I really think this has made my code cleaner and easier to maintain.

This was inspired by Miguel Castro's [Extreme WCF screen cast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) on DotNet Rocks TV with Carl Franklin - highly recommended screen cast !

Comment: thanks for your help.
sorry for my Ugly structure.

what i need is that:
a server.
all clients will registered in it.

n clients.
they could search assign type in the server.

-----------------
and ,when client request the search, server maybe not started.
in this case, i want to start the server, and may the server rediscovery all the running clients. and then, i could search the other clients.

Comment: Yes. It's a recommended way. +1

Comment: But your `Manager : IManager` is again a WCF service - which should **NOT** host another service inside itself! That's **NOT** a sound design! You need to keep your `ServiceHost` classes and your WCF service implementation classes strictly separate...

Comment: hi marc_s, Client can find each other, and send message to each other?

Comment: @GeminiYellow: yes, that should be possible - the code that wants to send a message needs to be a client to the service method that you want to call to

Comment: @ marc_s:thanks marc.
so my case should be like this:
0. when the Manager was closed, the child will open the managerhost.exe, and wait for the notify.then 
1. Manager Online -> Notify Child -> Child registed
2. Child get others Registed children info from Manager.
3. Child create a connection with other child with the info(maybe endpointaddress),open a pipe.
4. finish.

It right?

Comment: but  Extreme WCF screen cast  also have this problom, i can't start a service and createchannel to it in the same exe.